# height 100% on children, with parent without height in pixels

Tags: html, css, height

Okay, there are many questions like this. But it wont help.

So, I will NOT use flexbox, or display:table and display:table-cell, bcs both solutions break my responsive layout and I will NOT declare new breakpoints in flexbox. Okay?

**So, the code below is pretty well working. All three cells have same height. 100% of parrent div. Okay.**

```css
.row{
    background-color: grey;
height:300px;
}
.cell{
    display:block;
    float:left;
    height:100%;
}
#cell1{
    background-color: yellow;
}
#cell2{
    background-color: orange;
}
#cell3{
    background-color: #06C;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <div id="cell1" class="cell">Content 1</div>
    <div id="cell2" class="cell">Content 2<br>Content 2<br>Content 2<br>Content 2<br>Content 2<br>Content 2<br></div>
    <div id="cell3" class="cell">Content 3</div>
</div>
```

The problem - it is working only if parrent div have height set in pixels. If you remove height:300px; on .row class, or you will want change it for height in percentage, auto, min-height or something more flexible, height:100% on child divs will stop working and you will see something like this...

```css
.row{
    background-color: grey;
    min-height:100px;
    display:block;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.cell{
    display:block;
    float:left;
    height:100%;
}
#cell1{
    background-color: yellow;
}
#cell2{
    background-color: orange;
}
#cell3{
    background-color: #06C;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <div id="cell1" class="cell">Content 1</div>
    <div id="cell2" class="cell">Content 2<br>Content 2<br>Content 2<br>Content 2<br>Content 2<br>Content 2<br></div>
    <div id="cell3" class="cell">Content 3</div>
</div>
```

I was experimenting with overflow: hidden; with adding one more div with clearfix, nothing helped me.. In my layout is nothing with height set in pixels.

Comment: If it is not clear, i want result of first snippet without setting parent div in pixels.

Comment: _height:100% on child divs will stop working..._ No that is not correct. It still fills up 100% of the parent. But now the height is depending on the content.

Comment: If you won't use the acceptable solutions which were **designed** to solve your problem then there is not much we can offer.

Comment: .. and if those solution break your "responsive layout" then you are doing something wrong. There is no *magic* system for responsiveness, media queries and modern layout methods are what you need. I suggest you grasp the nettle and get a handle on them.

Comment: hey hey, the second snipet demonstrate that the .row (parent) div can have height depending on height of the content of child divs.. and first snippet demonstrate that height of all childs divs can be 100% heigh of that parent div.. so where is problem to combine this????

Comment: @B001ᛦ yes, it will stop working.. and you can see it in snippet.. content will make parrent div higher, but afterwards child divs will not follow 100% height of parent div..